# Is it necessary to use transaction scope for these lines

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two tables in Oracle one of them is MtcUnverified seconds is MtcExit

```
private bool Verify(Mtcexittran mtcExitTran)
{
    try
    {

        var mtcUnverified = _centraldbContext.Mtcunverifiedtran.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Transactionid.Equals(mtcExitTran.Transactionid));

        if (mtcUnverified == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        _centraldbContext.Mtcunverifiedtran.Remove(mtcUnverified);

        _centraldbContext.Mtcexittran.Add(mtcExitTran);

        _centraldbContext.SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       
        return false;
    }

}
```

My goal is to delete the record from mtcunverified table and insert it to mtcexit table. Do I need to use transactionscope in this code? Is there a possibility that the record will be deleted from the mtcunverified table and not inserted in mtcexit? If the record cannot be added to mtcexit, I want to rollback the deletion from the mtcunverified table. The savechanges method is already creating begin transactions. Therefore, if even one of the two processes is problematic, I think that savechanges will rollback the 2 process. Or do I have to use transactionscope? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation, under ["Save Data/Transaction"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#default-transaction-behavior), it says

> By default, if the database provider supports transactions, all
> changes in a single call to SaveChanges are applied in a transaction.
> If any of the changes fail, then the transaction is rolled back and
> none of the changes are applied to the database. This means that
> SaveChanges is guaranteed to either completely succeed, or leave the
> database unmodified if an error occurs.
>
> For most applications, this default behavior is sufficient. You should
> only manually control transactions if your application requirements
> deem it necessary.

So, unless you've done something to stop EF using transactions, the default should be fine.

If you want more advanced transaction control, with a transaction spanning multiple calls to `SaveChanges`, and with "savepoints" that you can roll back to, that's described in the same part of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I understand, if database cannot add record to mtcexit tran, the deletion of mtcunverified will be automatically rollback. My project leader said I should use transactionscope in such a process. So I asked to make sure that using transactionscope is unnecessary for this process. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I linked to the documentation of "EF core". The story is generally the same with older versions, but the details can be different when you want to do advanced things. Which version are you using?

A transaction scope probably won't hurt - but it's also probably unnessescary. Unless you want to have one transaction across multiple databases or similar.